# VS2012 Entity Framework Error - Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-4.1

I am using VS2012.
When I go an create a .edmx file, it creates the following structure:

```
->Model.edmx
-->Model.Context.tt
-->Model.Designercs
-->Model.edmx.diagram
-->Model.tt
```

From my understanding, VS2012 generates T4 templates (the .tt files) which generate the entities and context. The default entities generated in VS2012 are POCO entities.

I am able to add a table to the Model just fine.

When I do a compile, I get no errors.

When

I do the following:

```
    Model dbContext3 = new Model(); 

    var result = (from dd in dbContext3.tblWMt
                  select dd).ToList();
```

I get the following message at run time from System.Data.MetadataException :

```
   {"Unable to load the specified metadata resource."}
```

Any idea what may be going wrong. I did check the connection string and that looks correct.
As mentioned, I was able to even add a table from the designer just fine.

Below is the connection string:

```
   metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.\Sql2012;initial catalog=Phig;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=S4343;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework
```

Comment: Check the properties of the edmx file (open the edmx and right click on the designer surface and select "Properties"). In the property window check what is the option "Metadata Artifact Processing" set to - should be "Embed in Output Assembly". Show your connection string.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I do have it set to Embed in Output Assembly. Also I have put the connection string above.

Comment: Check if the resources are really embedded in your assembly. You can use ildasm for that. Also, can you post the stack trace?